# Switch Statement on Json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am wondering how do I make a switch statement in json?

```
{"Errors":{"key1":"afkafk"},"IsValid":false,"SuccessMessage":""}
```

I tried

```
switch(response)
{
   case response.Errors.key1:
    alert('test');
   default: 
}
```

But it seems to ignore my first case.

**Edit**

```
// if undefined then go to next if statement - I am not sure if I can do something 
// like !=== null
if (response.Errors.key1)
            {
               // display value of key1 
            }
else if(response.Errors.Key2)
{
   // display value of key2 differently
}
```

So that is what I am trying to do just with a switch statement.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `response` will never equal `response.Errors.key1`.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand `switch`. What do you think should it do?

Comment: Why won't it. response holds the json. I can do response.Errors.Key1 and it would print out the value. So I just need it too look at the key.

Comment: @delnan - I consider Errors to be a dictionary. I want to look at the keys and then do something based on the key it found.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is JavaScript code, not JSON (https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would be the correct syntax:

```
switch(response.Errors.key1)
{
    case 'afkafk':
        alert('test');
        break;
    default:
        alert('default');
}
```

But I suspect that in your case the following structure would be more adapted:

```
{ Errors: { key: 'key1', message: 'afkafk' }, IsValid: false, SuccessMessage: '' }
```

because it would allow you to switch on the key:

```
switch(response.Errors.key)
{
    case 'key1':
        alert(response.Errors.message);
        break;
    default:
        alert('default');
}
```

Comment: Hmm I was looking to look at what at the key values in Errors. So if It is key1 => do this. If it is key2 do that. I guess I might have to loop through all the keys and have if statements checking then(even though for the keys that I am isolating out are special ones and nothing else would be in the Errors array hence why I tried to do a switch statement)

Comment: @chobo2, if you want to achieve this I would recommend you the following JSON structure: `{"Errors":{"key":"key1", message: "afkafk"},"IsValid":false,"SuccessMessage":""}`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to switch on the value `key1` instead of the name `key1`.

```
switch (response.Errors.key1) {
  case 'afkafk':
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to switch based on the value of key1? Switch statements need to be able to match the variable you pass to the switch statement with the value of a case statement, so the following would work, although I'm not sure if it's what you're after:

```
switch (response.Errors.key1) {
  case 'afkafk': //do something
  break;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to match the key up and do something based on the key. So if I see key1 then I want to display the value in key1 differently then something in key2.

Comment: Ah right, I see now. In that case you'll want to iterate the properties on Errors. You can do it like this: `for (var key in response.Errors) {
  switch(response.Errors[key]) {
    case 'afkafk':
   //do something
   break;
  }
}`